# Is there an option in sed to print the lines edited on the standard output?

Tags: unix, sed

For separation of concerns, configuration edition in production is done by a ops or support, not development team. What is reliable option to enable ops/support to check the sed editions are correct?

A number of lines edited or all edited lines on the standard output would work for example.
Does sed offer such options?

Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like you need a versionning system (Subversion? cvs ? git ?) (for anything text/script/source). That will allow you to see what changed, have tags, branches, ability to revert to last known good version, etc.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you want.  You can simply do a context diff between the input and the output, or you can arrange for `sed` to only print the lines it changes by using `-n` to suppress the normal printing and adding `p` after any substitute commands.  If you're using `a` or `i`, you'll have to work a bit harder.

Answer (score 1):

If you are familiar with diff (or vim), you can check the modifications without modifying the files like:

```
diff ORIGINAL_FILE <(sed 's/foo/bar/g' ORIGINAL_FILE)
```

Or:

```
vimdiff ORIGINAL_FILE <(sed 's/foo/bar/g' ORIGINAL_FILE)
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is there an option in sed to print the lines edited on the standard output?

You can use `p` command in sed:

```
sed -n -i.bak 's/search/replace/pg' config-file.txt
```

This will print each line after performing search/replace.

Comment: Thanks anhubava, but i am looking for a solution that prints *only* the lines that have been effectively changed, this will print all the lines.